# Wrong default value for SQL Servers datetime type

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-2.2

Let's assume a `Category` n-m `Blog` relation:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Categories(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Title NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    Created datetime NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Categories PRIMARY KEY(Id)
)
CREATE TABLE Posts(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Subject NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    Body NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Posts PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
CREATE TABLE PostCategory(
    CategoryId INT NOT NULL,
    PostId INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_PostCategory PRIMARY KEY (CategoryId, PostId),
    FOREIGN KEY ([CategoryId]) REFERENCES [Categories]([Id]),
    FOREIGN KEY ([PostId]) REFERENCES [Posts]([Id])
)
```

After scaffolding the database (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db#reverse-engineer-your-model) I started my first query:

```cs
var postsWithLatestCategoryTimestamp = (
        from post in db.Posts
        let latestCategoryTimestamp =
            (
                from relation in post.PostCategory
                orderby relation.Category.Created descending
                select relation.Category.Created
            )
            .FirstOrDefault()
        select new
        {
            post.Id, post.Subject, latestCategoryTimestamp
        }
    ).ToList();
```

I got

> **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException**: 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

The reason:
EntityFramework Core uses the wrong default value (`'0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000'.` instead of `'1753-01-01T00:00:00.000'`):

```sql
SELECT [post].[Id], [post].[Subject], COALESCE((
    SELECT TOP(1) [relation.Category].[Created]
    FROM [PostCategory] AS [relation]
    INNER JOIN [Categories] AS [relation.Category] ON [relation].[CategoryId] = [relation.Category].[Id]
    WHERE [post].[Id] = [relation].[PostId]
    ORDER BY [relation.Category].[Created] DESC
), '0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000') AS [latestCategoryTimestamp]
FROM [Posts] AS [post]
```

**How can I fix it without touching existing database?**

---

By the way, `OnModelCreating()` is well scaffolded:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Categories>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.Created).HasColumnType("datetime");
    //...
});
```

Comment: Can you change your db schema to datetime2?

Comment: @Piotr No, as I said `without touching existing database`.

Comment: Can you use .First() instead of .FirstOrDefault() and deal with the null values? Check also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56170828/wrong-default-value-for-sql-servers-datetime-type?noredirect=1#comment98968547_56170828

Comment: Effectively, you're asking for the *minimum* `Created` value per post ID and Subject. In SQL you'd write a `GROUP BY`, not a nested query with a `TOP 1`.

Comment: @Piotr I could use `.DefaultIfEmpty(new DateTime(1753,1,1)).First()` or `post.PostCategory.Any() ? ([subquery]).First() : new DateTime(1753,1,1)`. Both will end up in 1+n queries :-( Log: _"Warning The LINQ expression 'First()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally."_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might look like EF Core bug, but to me it's more like incorrect query.

Imagine EF Core somehow translates "correctly" the CLR `DateTime` default to the SqlServer minimum supported date. When you get the materialized result, how you will know if `latestCategoryTimestamp` is the default? Checking against SqlServer min date? What if you are running the query against in-memory database or some other database? May be you would say they have to convert it back in memory? By why database min value should be mapped to `default(DateTime)`? How about `DateTime.MinValue` then?

The conclusion is that there is no correct  mapping of `default(DateTime)`. The question is, why using "magic" value to represent missing value? Databases provide `NULL` for that, and C# (CLR) - nullable types.

So the most logical way is to use nullable type. All you need to change in your query is add a cast to `DateTime?` here

```
select (DateTime?)relation.Category.Created
```

But since all you need here is the *maximum* date, it would be sufficient to use `Max` method (but again with nullable overload):

```
let latestCategoryTimestamp = post.PostCategory.Max(link => (DateTime?)link.Category.Created)
```

But whatever approach you choose, all you need then would be to account for `Nullable<DateTime>` property of the materialized object. The good thing is that the `null` will indicate missing post category regardless of the database type.